# Another good ol' segmentation error in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I know that people ask a LOT of segmentation err questions here, but I've put my effort in solving this problem for more than three hour and still wasn't able to solve this. :/ So here is my code:

```
c     sinle event analysis

  implicit real(a-h,o-z)
  real day(12), nmonth(12), year(12), clas(12),
 $ hour(12), nmin(12)
  integer mark(12)
  real tst(12), D(12), avgP(12,6), avgA(12,6)
  integer k, m, n, g

  real time(2054904), proa(2054904), prob(2054904), w1(2054904),
 $ w2(2054904), w3(2054904), w4(2054904) 

  D(1) = 31; D(2) = 28; D(3) = 31; D(4) = 30; D(5) = 31;
  D(6) = 30; D(7) = 31; D(8) = 31; D(9) = 30; D(10) = 31;
  D(11) = 30; D(12) = 31

  open(100,file='singleE.dat')

  do i=1, 12
   tst(i)=0
  enddo
```

900   do i=1, 12
       read(100, 1150) day(i), nmonth(i), year(i),
     $  hour(i), nmin(i), clas(i)

```
   do j=1, 12
    if (int(nmonth(i)).EQ.(13-j)) then
    tst(i) = tst(i) + D(12-j)
    nmonth(i) = nmonth(i)-1
    endif
   enddo

   tst(i) = tst(i) + day(i) + (year(i) - 2010)*365
 $  + (hour(i) + nmin(i)/60)/24 

   if (year(i) > real(2011)) then 
    tst(i) = tst(i) + 1
   endif
  enddo

  open(200,file='hole.dat',status='OLD')

  k = 0

  do i=1, 2054904
   read(200,950) time(i), proa(i), prob(i),
 $ w1(i), w2(i), w3(i), w4(i) 
  enddo

  mark = 0

  do i=1, 12
   do j=1, 2054904
    k = k + 1
    if(abs(tst(i)-time(j))<0.0001) then
     mark(i) = k
    endif
   enddo
  enddo      

  n = 5;

  do i= 1, 12
   do j= 1,6
    avgP(i,j) = 0
    avgA(i,j) = 0
   enddo
  enddo



  do i=1, 12
   if (mark(i).EQ.0) then
    go to 750
   endif

   do j = (mark(i)-(n+1)*1440), (mark(i)-n*1440)
    avgP(i,1) = avgP(i,1) + proa(j) 
    avgP(i,2) = avgP(i,2) + prob(j)
    avgP(i,3) = avgP(i,3) + w1(j)
    avgP(i,4) = avgP(i,4) + w2(j)
    avgP(i,5) = avgP(i,5) + w3(j)
    avgP(i,6) = avgP(i,6) + w4(j)
   enddo

   do g = (mark(i)+n*1440), (mark(i)+(n+1)*1440)
    avgA(i,1) = avgA(i,1) + proa(g)
    avgA(i,2) = avgA(i,2) + prob(g)
    avgA(i,3) = avgA(i,3) + w1(g)
    avgA(i,4) = avgA(i,4) + w2(g)
    avgA(i,5) = avgA(i,5) + w3(g)
    avgA(i,6) = avgA(i,6) + w4(g)
   enddo
```

750    print *, avgP(i,1), avgP(i,2), avgP(i,3), avgP(i,4),
     $  avgP(i,5), avgP(i,6)

```
  enddo
```

850   close(i)

950   FORMAT(F12.7,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,
     $ 2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3)

1150  FORMAT(F2.0,1x,F2.0,1x,F4.0,1x,F2.0,1x,F2.0,4x F3.1)

```
  end
```

The part that is causing me trouble is the loop here:

```
  do i=1, 12
   if (mark(i).EQ.0) then
    go to 750
   endif

   do j = (mark(i)-(n+1)*1440), (mark(i)-n*1440)
    avgP(i,1) = avgP(i,1) + proa(j) 
    avgP(i,2) = avgP(i,2) + prob(j)
    avgP(i,3) = avgP(i,3) + w1(j)
    avgP(i,4) = avgP(i,4) + w2(j)
    avgP(i,5) = avgP(i,5) + w3(j)
    avgP(i,6) = avgP(i,6) + w4(j)
   enddo

   do g = (mark(i)+n*1440), (mark(i)+(n+1)*1440)
    avgA(i,1) = avgA(i,1) + proa(g)
    avgA(i,2) = avgA(i,2) + prob(g)
    avgA(i,3) = avgA(i,3) + w1(g)
    avgA(i,4) = avgA(i,4) + w2(g)
    avgA(i,5) = avgA(i,5) + w3(g)
    avgA(i,6) = avgA(i,6) + w4(g)
   enddo


  enddo
```

Using gdb, I found out that the 'j' loop is causing trouble. All of the parameters are fine, but every time I execute the program the 'j' loop goes only once. The peculiar thing is that as 'i' increases the processes start to cripple one by one. for example, at i = 1 the loop executes well. Then, at i = 2, avgP(i,6) = avgP(i,6) + w4(j) causes the seg fault. At i =  3, avgP(i,5) = avgP(i,5) + w3(j) causes the seg fault and in the end at i = 7, entire loop doesn't work. What a strange error! Hope that I can get some help with this.

Comment: Spend another 5 minutes or so formatting your code correctly.  Make it easy for us to help you.  Then tell us that you have already used your compiler to see that your code doesn't wander off the end of any of the arrays.  And, of course, always use `implicit none` -- I can't see this being a problem for you as you already explicitly declare the type of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The loop

`do j=1, 12
    if (int(nmonth(i)).EQ.(13-j)) then
    tst(i) = tst(i) + D(12-j)
    nmonth(i) = nmonth(i)-1
    endif
   enddo`

potentially tries to access the value `D(0)` when `j=12` however `D` is dimensioned `1:12` so who knows what is being written to `tst` and its consequences.

This should be caught by turning on bounds checking.